# What is the best Approach for Updating UI in MVVM Architecture?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mvvm

I am new to java and mvvm architecture.
In my project I am trying to fetch some data through an api.
So for this purpose I have got three files, mainActivity, apiRepository, and viewModel.
The user has to enter some information and then click submit, on button click the app fetches data from the api according to the information given by the user, but if the user enters some wrong information, there is a popup (linear layout) which appears showing the error (achieved with the help of visible and gone).

Question: So basically I want to ask that whether I should update the ui, i.e., update the data given by the api from mainActivity file or from the view model?

If through mainActivity, then will it still be considered as MVVM?
and If from the viewModel class, then how can I get the data binding object of the mainActivity inside the viewModel class?

Comment: No you should update your UI elements from View(Activity/fragment), when you received your response in your viewModel, you can get that data from Activity using observable from activity to update your UI elements

Comment: But will that still be called MVVM? because I will be exposing the response to the View file.

Comment: Actually you got your response in your ViewModel only, and you are observing that response, whether the data has been received from APIs or not, from the View through ViewModel , that's what MVVM has been. If you need to show the response in UI then this was the way. As you should not handle UI elements in ViewModel, so you can get the data from ViewModel and set it in View.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/intro